# Parameter Not valid” Error in VB.NET While retrive image to picturebox from sql database

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim str As String
Dim dr As SqlDataReader

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    str = "select * from llr where llrno='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(str, con)
    con.Open()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If dr.HasRows Then
        dr.Read()
        Dim img As Byte() = DirectCast(dr("img"), Byte())
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(img)
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    End If
    dr.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the data in the server is correct? Also what datatype is it?

Comment: PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms) display error for parameter is not valid.how to solve that problem

Comment: am used datatype is image in sqldatabase

Comment: I have used an almost identical line in a recent project, you should check the value of `img` after you fill it using `DirectCast`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be with the previous line, try changing to this:

```
Dim img As Byte() = dr("img")
```

and see if you get the same error.

Comment: the database value store <Binary data> in image.Its correct ah?

Comment: what is a problem in my program

Comment: Is your program writing these images? If so can you post the code that writes them to the DB?